# Can't sync Android Calendar Events (created from my app) with the Google Calendar

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

My Android Google Account has sync options enabled in Settings (For Calendar/Contacts ect).

When I add new event from the native calendar app it syncs with the web Google Calendar.
When I add new event programmatically, although it appears in the native Android Calendar App, it never syncs with the Google Calendar on my account.

I searched for various snippets online and tried different things, my events (inserted from my app) are never appearing in the Google Calendar (only the local phone calendar).

This is how I am inserting an event:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     accountName = getAccount().name;
     accountType = getAccount().type;

    setCalendarVisiblityAndSync();
    addEvent(); //add single test event (this one appears in local calendar)
}

private void setCalendarVisiblityAndSync(){
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);

    Uri uri = asSyncAdapter(ContentUris.withAppendedId(Calendars.CONTENT_URI, 1),accountName, accountType);
    cr.update(uri, values, null, null);

}

public long addEvent() {

    DateTime dateFrom = new DateTime().withDayOfMonth(20).withHourOfDay(11);
    DateTime dateTo = new DateTime().withDayOfMonth(20).withHourOfDay(12);

    long startMillis = 0;
    long endMillis = 0;

    startMillis = dateFrom.getMillis();
    endMillis = dateTo.getMillis();

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
    values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);

    String title = "ANDROID EVENT FROM MY APP";
    values.put(Events.TITLE, title);

    String description = "ANDROID EVENT FROM MY APP DESCRIPTION";
    values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, description);

    values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
    values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, dateFrom.getZone().toTimeZone().getDisplayName());

    values.put(Events.HAS_ALARM, true);

    Uri eventUri = asSyncAdapter(Events.CONTENT_URI,accountName,accountType);
    Uri uri = cr.insert(eventUri, values);

    // get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
    long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());

    return eventID;
}

public Account getAccount() {
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
    Account account = accounts[0];

    return account;

}



//The static function below is a snippet of code I found as a suggestion on another thread (but I am not sure if I am using it right ?!)
    static Uri asSyncAdapter(Uri uri, String account, String accountType) {
        return uri.buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(android.provider.CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER,"true")
            .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account)
            .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType).build();
}
```

The functions above come from different threads and I combined them myself in an attempt to achieve successful sync with Google Calendar but it is not working.

EDIT: I am also getting this message in the Log window:

```
  /*05-02 10:40:16.670: W/EventHandler(29147):        com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
 05-02 10:40:16.670: W/EventHandler(29147): {
05-02 10:40:16.670: W/EventHandler(29147):   "errors": [
05-02 10:40:16.670: W/EventHandler(29147):     {
05-02 10:40:16.670: W/EventHandler(29147):       "reason": "invalid",
05-02 10:40:16.670: W/EventHandler(29147):       "domain": "global",
```

05-02 10:40:16.670: W/EventHandler(29147):       "message": "Invalid time zone    definition for start time." */

Comment: Have you managed to fix the issue. Actually am also facing the same issue.

Comment: I have not, I abandoned the issue ever since... In case I find a solution I will share it.

Comment: have you solved this problem yet?  I face the same issue, can only sync with my phone calendar...  I read google api, it is said that "OAuth2" is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in "dateFrom.getZone().toTimeZone().getDisplayName()".
What it returns is the localized name of the timezone, for example "Pacific Standard Time". Such string version you can show to the user but server probably expects the timezone id instead. Try using dateFrom.getZone().getID().

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't have to do the insert by yourself, delegate it to your mobile's native calendar. You can use the Intent to do it.

[Intents for adding events to calendar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-insert)

it will automatically open your mobile's native calendar and you can refresh your view once it is added to reflect in your app.